# Show when user is online

Tags: feature-request, users, app-request, script-request

I apologize if this already exist, but i could not find it.

My question is, is there a **real-time** display next to the user question if that user is still on line or not.

Something like this (green circle) next to the OP info.

[image: on line]

Having that information might help in posting comment and asking for information or clarification on the OP while the user is still active. Otherwise posting a comment might not be seen for long time, and it slows down the Answering significantly. Most OP ask a question and then after a while without comment or answer just walk away (been tired of waiting for a respond). I find it convoluted, when posting a comment like a hour later, then not getting a reply for days.

Since there is confusion as for the use of this information let me clarify:

Main purpose would be to be able to keep a new OP interested in providing a quick reply to the question while the user is still on-line and waiting. Once that waiting period gets to long many users walk away and in many case not to be seen again (since they look for answers elsewhere). This would drastically improve the Open Question to Answer ratio.

Comment: The StackExchange network is intended for Q&A only.  By limiting the "social network" aspects of a forum the quality of the site to ask questions and get answers massively improves.  Your best bet if you want to get into some real-time chat with the members of this (and in particular the StackOverflow site) is to go to the chat section: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @scunliffe I do not think you understood my question. It is not about chatting or socializing, it is about clarifying the OP while the user is still there. Making a comment to stale question then maybe getting a reply in days or weeks, is just counterproductive.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I think that if the comment is worth making, then you should make it regardless of if the Op is online or not.

Comment: @RohitGupta An example: a OP starts a question and stays on line for next hour or even a day. Then the OP moves on not to be seen for months or Years. Making a comment while the OP is on line could lead to a answer. Making a comment in to the black hole (no OP) does not solve the question.